# What is PhantomJS script poo_master/price_parse/resource_cache doing

Tags: magento, phantomjs

My Magento website is constantly visited by several Linux-hosts running a PhantomJS script with the following name:

file:///home/poo_master/price_parse/resource_cache/[some_random_15-digits_file_name..]tmp2.htm

Anyone have a clue what this is, can't find any reliable information anywhere, so as a last attempt I try reaching out to you guys (sorry if the question is irrelevant, but again.. need to figure out if I'm being hacked or what)

Comment: You can't know what scripts they run, where does this filename come from? And haven't you blocked them in .htaccess already?

Comment: I think they are proper blocked in .htaccess, but I can still see the traffic through my Zopim chat since Zopim hasn't blocket it. That's also where I get the filename/path from. But as long as they keep on running 'something' against my site, I'd like to know if I need to prepare for an attack - and how (if they change their path, they will no longer be blocked through .htaccess)

Comment: So filename/path is the requested URL on your server? Or is it the referer in your logs?

Comment: Filename/paht is not on my server, seems more like the local paht on the Linux-server running the PhantomJS script against my server. But because the filename is always some random 15 characters +tmp2.html I guess each file perhaps contain some reference to files on my server.

Comment: Zopim chat, you say? I'm guessing there's a widget in your HTML that loads a Zopim chat instance on your site's pages?

Comment: Yes.. there is a Zopim chat widget on my site, which enables me to see who's visiting my page. Usually the URL that the customer visits displays, but that is not the case here.. Here I only see some kind of local address from the visitor, probably containing some reference to one of my pages. I have not seen this kind of traffic until a few weeks ago, and now it's visiting me about every minute. Traffic appears to come from Riga, London and Stockholm - usually hidden behind some anynomous dns provider. So it looks suspicious...

Comment: Well, it seems they scraped your pages and now open them in browser on a localhost which is why Zopim reports such filenames. The attack has already taken place :) So, what's with PhantomJS? Does Zopim report it as the client's browser?

Comment: Zopim reports the following User Agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Agree with @Enigmativity, it's not about programming. Someone parsed your site, Espen and now is double parsing it using PhantomJS.

Comment: Agree. I realize that it's not possible to see exactly what's behind the PhantomJS activity, and I thank you all for helping me clarifying what kind of activity this most likely is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you may be able to get help on https://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: did you find out what the script user could be gaining from this effort?

Comment: No.. I guess it is some kind of price parsing from someone like TradeDoubler/Kelkoo etc.. I know they do some checking, but when I asked their customer service they told me that they did not cause this traffic. But who knows what the guys on customer support knows..